# My validator fails when userRepositary try to save new User in DataBase

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, validation

I try to create my validate annotation.

When validation fails it's work good. I get a message about. But when validation passes I get RollbackException.

What I do in my validate annotation?

I want to check a unique email in the user table. Therefore, I have created @annotation:

```
package ru.project.domain.validation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueEmailValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface UniqueEmail {

    public String message() default "e-mail exist!";

    public Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};

}
```

I have created Validator:

```
package ru.project.domain.validation;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import ru.project.service.UserService;

public class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value != null && !userService.isEmailAlredyUse(value);
    }

}
```

When I enter not-unique email I get message "e-mail exist!"

But when I enter unique email I get error:

> 2019-07-07 13:14:09.770 ERROR 11680 --- [io-8080-exec-10]
>   o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during
>   managed flush [HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.]
>   2019-07-07 13:14:09.777 ERROR 11680 --- [io-8080-exec-10]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
>   commit JPA transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
>   transaction] with root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   ru.project.domain.validation.UniqueEmailValidator.isValid(UniqueEmailValidator.java:17)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   ru.project.domain.validation.UniqueEmailValidator.isValid(UniqueEmailValidator.java:1)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:171)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:68)
>   ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar:6.0.17.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:73) ...

The function isValid is called twice. When validated after push button on the form and when userRepository try to save new User.

I will show what debugger shows me every time.

When push button on the form(unique email):
[image]

When userRepository try to save new User:
[image]

UPDATE: isEmailAlreadyUse:

```
public boolean isEmailAlredyUse(String value) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(value);
        if(user != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

During the second run userService = null:
[image]

Comment: did you check `isEmailAlredyUse`  method ?  it looks like it returns `null`

Comment: I have checked now. It turns out, when a second time isValid is performed userService = null. How can I fix it?

Comment: Look the picture in question

Comment: it looks like jpa will do the validation again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47245122/spring-hibernate-autowired-is-null-in-constraintvalidator

Comment: can you please try to annotate your validation class with `@Component`

Comment: Try... Didn't help.

Comment: I read the link above. But I don't understand what I have to do and where I have to do this...

Comment: I right understand what when I try to save user, it's run hibernate. Hibernate don't run in Spring context.. Spring context doesn't know what he should autowired userService that hibernate autowired. Therefore, I have to tell Spring that he should autowired userService in Hibernate?

Comment: Therefore, Should I tune persistence.xml?

Comment: @AlexanderLopatin добавил вам примерный ответ. Прочитайте отдельно про bindResult

Comment: @AlexanderLopatin , can you share the  full stacktrace, paste it in the https://pastebin.com/ , I am trying to reproduce so backtracking from the log, do add

Comment: @Avi I shared the full stacktrace [HERE](https://pastebin.com/J5yC5ZYB)

Comment: is it possible to add the build.gradle/pom.xml along with  applcation.yml / .properties

Comment: @Avi pom.xml: https://pastebin.com/0EVRWSgG

Comment: @Avi application.yml: https://pastebin.com/5p2rULXU There's only datasource and email settings

Comment: @Avi I add next property spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none in application.yml. But... What is it? I don't understand what is it. I think that twice check is excess. And I can turn off it. But I don't understand what I did. What check do I turn off? And... Why autowired return null when the second check is run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One decision is to turn off a check when 'hibernate' save an entity in the database. To do this you need to set next property in your application.properties

> spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

#### ExtendedEmailValidator.java:

```java
@Email(message="Please provide a valid email address")
@Pattern(regexp=".+@.+\\..+", message="Please provide a valid email address")
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
public @interface ExtendedEmailValidator {
    String message() default "Please provide a valid email address";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

How to use it? In your entity add this:

```java
    @Column
    @ExtendedEmailValidator(message = "custom message")
    private String email;
```

in your `@Controller` try this:

```java
@PostMapping
public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());

if (userExists != null) {
  bindingResult
               .rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                            "There is already a user registered with the email provided");
}

if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
    modelAndView.setViewName("registration");
    return modelAndView;
}

/*
Other code
*/
}
```

Comment: If I don't mistake Controller should run without annotation because all logic of check is presented in @Controler. Info about the error is added manually.